# preg_match dynamic text from string and echo

Tags: php

I am trying to get dynamic text from a string using preg_match

```
$desc = 'this is some text big <a href="//example.com/dynamicID">//example.com/dynamicID</a><br> and some more text here';

$desiredtext = preg_match("//example.com/.*?", $desiredtext, $desc);

echo $desiredtext; //this should return me only //example.com/dynamicID
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following: (updated!)

```
if(preg_match("/(?<=href=")([^"]*)/", $desc,$matches)) $desiredtext=$matches[1];
```

It uses a lookbehind group searching for `href="`. The capturing group `([^"]*)` will then grab anything following that up to the next `"`. It is up to you to tune the regexp to suit your requirements.

**Response to your comment:**

Extend the first search group `()` to include "example.com" and then get the result from `matches[1]` instead of `matches[0]`:

```
preg_match('/(example.com[^&]*)/',$desc,$matches);
$part = $matches[1]; 
echo $part;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the problem is there is multiple href in text how to find exactly what we need? some times the desired text in 2nd href and some times in 7th href.

Comment: Your second and third arguments are reversed, and you're storing 1, 0 or `FALSE` where you want the match to be stored

Comment: Can you describe exactly, "what we need"? Are you looking for a specific URL or dies it have to be in specific `<a>`?

Comment: I am looking for a URL which is dynamic I don't want an anchor tags, I just want the dynamic URL like this `//example.com/dynamicID` this part of URL is changing `dynamicID`

Comment: @sidyll: thanks for pointing that out! I only looked at the regexp at first. Corrected it now.

Comment: Thanks :-) and @KenDev if you need global matches, use `preg_match_all`. The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) is your friend

Comment: @cars10 its not working, giving me an error `syntax error, unexpected '('`

Comment: ok I have found the solution. 
`preg_match('/example.com([^&]*)/',$desc,$matches);
$part = $matches[0];
echo $part;` now problem is, showing `example.com/dynamicID` along with `</a><br> and some more text` so i want to remove the rest of the code and only keep `example.com/dynamicID` how to fix this now?